# What's the meaning of 'In easy-to-read type'?

Tags: books

I have just bought a book:

[image]

What's the meaning of 'In easy-to-read type'?

Does it mean it's not the original version, but a simplified one?

Comment: It most likely means that it's printed in a large, simple typeface aimed at young children. The book may also be abridged to simplify it, but “easy-to-read type” specifically refers to the appearance of the text.

Comment: Your question is being down voted because it seems out of place here. Perhaps it will suit [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: **8** *Printing* d. A size or style of printed or typewritten characters; a typeface: *a sans-serif type*. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“In easy-to-read type” means that the book is published using a font or typeface that is clear and easily read.  End-notes in the previews of *[Mother West Wind's Neighbors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048642846X)* at amazon.com indicate that the work is an “unabridged republication of ... the work originally published in 1910.”  Thus, the text has not been simplified, but it's possible a more-easily-read typeface like *[Century Schoolbook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_Schoolbook#Century_Schoolbook)* (1919) or *[Primer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primer_%28typeface%29#Typefaces)* (1953) may have been substituted for the original typeface.

Comment: Not only a nice clear typeface, but often at a somewhat larger font size than usual. This will usually mean a larger page size and/or more pages (with less text) than the original.